# Cannot mute audiosource after returing to the scene (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello i have a menu scene where i have a mute button and a empty gameobject with audiosource and dontdestroyonload script attached to it. Here is the code from the gameobject.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Backgorund_Music_Manger : MonoBehaviour 
{
    AudioSource ads;
    public GameObject BackgroundMusic;
    bool play_sound = true;

    void Awake()
    {
        ads = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        if(SceneManager.music == true)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }

        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        }

        SceneManager.music = true;
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        if(SceneManager.currentScene == 4)
        {
            ads.volume = 0.1f;
        }
        else
        {
            ads.volume = 1f;
        }
    }

    public void stop_sound()
    {
        ads = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        if(play_sound == true)
        {
            ads.Pause();
            play_sound = false;
        }

        else
        {
            ads.Play();
            play_sound = true;
        }
    }
}
```

after going back to menu the mute button stops working.

Help

Comment: First, you should really redefine your programming style and structure. Second, you should really redefine the way you ask questions. Third, we can't say what's happening if you don't say how the button works.

Comment: there is a button in the first scene of the game which calls stop_sound() function when clicked and this script is attached to the gameobject that has the audiosource that plays the music. the code in awake function prevents the gameobject to be multiple copies when you return to the scene.